# How to make an addition Operation inside of a function in php?

Tags: php

i made a function that has an addition operation inside.. but when i call the function it shows an error

`A non-numeric value encountered in...`

my function is like this:

```
function get_pages($start){
echo '
<a href="page/'. $start + 1 .'">Next</a>
<a href="page/'. $start - 1 .'">Previous</a>
'
}
```

Calling function

```
get_pages($_GET['page']);
```

please can you give any solution for it?

Comment: try this one's `get_pages((int)$_GET['page']);`

Comment: tnx i tried but not working 

Comment: Left this one `get_pages((int)$_GET['page'])` and change this `$start - 1` into `$start>0? $start - 1 : $start` and use `++$start` instead of `$start + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first check if the passed value is_numeric (number or numeric string) and then group the operation together before concatenating it to a string:

```
function get_pages($start){
  if(is_numeric($start)){
   echo '
     <a href="page/'. ($start + 1) .'">Next</a>
     <a href="page/'. ($start - 1) .'">Previous</a>
   ';
  }
}
```